# Can CircleCI run a conditional step even on failure

Tags: continuous-integration, conditional-statements, circleci

I'm attempting to upload test results as a separate step from executing tests even when one of the tests fails. But I only want to upload results from specific branches.

Can `when:` be used this way? Is there a better alternative?

```
- when: always
    condition:
      matches:
        pattern: '^dev$'
        value: << pipeline.git.branch >>
    steps:
      - run:
          name: Upload Test Results
          command: <code here>
```

The code above results in a build error: `Unable to parse YAMLmapping values are not allowed here in 'string', condition:`

https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#the-when-attribute

Answer (score 0):

It can, I was just using the wrong syntax.

```
- when:
    condition:
      matches:
        pattern: '^dev$'
        value: << pipeline.git.branch >>
    steps:
      - run:
          name: Upload Test Results
          when: always
          command: <code here>
```